# How to generate an image file of a workflow inside a Symfony controller?

Tags: image, symfony, workflow, graphviz

I want to create an image file of a Symfony workflow from inside of a controller.

The documentation only shows how to do this inside the console. I already installed the GraphViz library via composer but I could not find a method that can convert the workflow definition to an image.

`php bin/console workflow:dump workflow-name | dot -Tsvg -o graph.svg`

I hope that this is not the only way to do it?!

Comment: what's your question exactly. because you need some software to turn that description of a workflow into an image. so whether you call the code in that command from the command line or you call the code in that command from a controller is essentially the same. but the question on turning (for example) dot-notation into an image ... you essentially can include a `exec` call in some service or something to do this very same thing.

Comment: I would like to avoid using the exec command. I disabled it on the server.

The question is if there is a "native" php equivalent to that code.

Comment: technically it's absolutely possible. I don't know of any though...

Comment: Well, the command call this class i believe : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Workflow/Dumper/GraphvizDumper.php so just check if it's declared as a service and you can simply inject it and use it from a controller or whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Symfony provides you solution for dumping workflow as GraphViz(dot) or PlantUML(puml) format. It does not convert it to image. You must do it yourself with exec or with this alternatives for dot files:

- Pear package(not maintained): https://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz
- PHP library(not maintained): https://code.google.com/archive/p/canviz/
- Client side library: https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/

I didn`t find any solution for converting puml to image without PlantUML binaries.